# listener argument must be of type Function error using socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

With the below function using socket io to join the connection for making workspace getting error of

> The "listener" argument must be of type Function.

How to solve this error, below I have pasted the entire error, I'm new to socketio what is the best way to feed the requirements as expected by the `io.on()` function.

```
export const roomJoin = (socket, io, msg) => {
        if (msg.room_id) {
            socket.join(msg.room_id, () => {
            io.on('room_join', function(socket){
                socket.emit('request',{ status: true, msg: "room join", room_id: msg.room_id });
                return
              });
            })

        } else {
            socket.emit('room_join', { status: false, message: "Invalid/Missing data" });
        }
    }
```

Getting this error

```
--------------------->connected EUFilhEfZmuXKjsIAAAA
------------------------->workspace_room_join {
  msg: {
    workspace_id: '5e29d571495f2e0043d2ddef',
    token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlMjlkNTcxNDk1ZjJlMDA0M2QyZGRlZiIsImVtYWlsIjoiZmFyaGFuNzAxMUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU3OTk3ODMxMCwiZXhwIjoxNTgwNTgzMTEwfQ.ZlvVanwTMGcD5sXp0-T-W3VImSGhus5i5aDem1-hUTQ'
  }
}
events.js:64
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:64:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:226:3)
    at Namespace.addListener (events.js:284:10)
    at Server.<computed> [as on] (/Users/user/Documents/weaverse-sockets-version2/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:505:29)
    at /Users/user/Documents/weaverse-sockets-version2/dist/controller/roomJoin.js:62:16
    at /Users/user/Documents/weaverse-sockets-version2/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:255:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```